# Задача "Военная база"; поиск в ширину, глубину

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Есть задача ["Военная база"](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=413):

> Со спутника-шпиона получено
> изображение в некотором волновом
> диапазоне сверхсекретной военной базы
> предполагаемого противника. База
> расположена на Антарктиде, все
> постройки на ней высечены из кубов
> льда и имеют на фотографии квадратную
> форму и не имеют общих фрагментов стен
> ненулевой длины (по всей видимости,
> это сделано в целях маскировки от
> локаторов, работающих в инфракрасном
> спектре). Благодаря мастерству
> операторов оказалось, что стены разных
> построек параллельны границам
> фотографии.
>
> Для того, чтобы составить сверхсрочный
> отчет для командования, необходимо
> узнать, сколько зданий находятся на
> базе. Напишите программу, которая это
> сделает.
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> В первой строке входного файла
> INPUT.TXT записаны числа N и M (1 <=
> M, N <= 500) – размеры фотографии в
> пикселях по вертикали и по
> горизонтали. Следующие N строк
> содержат по M символов каждая: символ
> '.' соответствует пустому месту, '#' –
> элементу постройки.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите
> единственное число – количество
> построек на базе.

Идей, как её написать, нет. Уместен ли тут поиск в ширину?
Напишите реализацию поиска в ширину и глубину в двумерном массиве. Спасибо.

Comment: @username76 Почитайте на [e-maxx.ru](http://e-maxx.ru/algo) про обходы в ширину и глубину

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слабо вижу как можно использовать поиск в ширину или в глкбину, это же не древовидная тсруктура. Сходу могу предложить такое решение: считываете строки, в строке ищете символы "#" только если их несколько, это означает начало постройки (стена). Дальше считываете новую строку, ищете в ней тоже самое. Если нашли, значит постройка закончилась, инкрементируете счетчик. Можно завести какой-нибудь вектор, куда складывать начало и конец стены и проверять эти же коррдинаты в векторе после каждого считывания.

Comment: почему не древовидная? очень даже древовидная

Comment: @username76 обычно поиск в ширину на двумерном поле (лабиринты и т.п.) называют "волновым алгоритмом" или "методом заливки", а писать код за Вас тут никто не будет

Comment: Спасибо, я и не просил полностью написать за меня.

Answer (score 1):

Обходишь все элементы массива по порядку при этом выполняя следующее: проверяешь является ли элемент стеной, если да то проверяешь 4 элемента массива по сторонам света (4 штуки) если какой-либо элемент массива имеет индексацию, то присваеваешь текущему элементу этот индекс, если нет то присваеваешь текущий индекс и при этом инкрементируешь его. Количество на выходе будет индекс - 1.